# google sheets / excel duplicate high value in row -> index column issue

Tags: google-sheets

excel....Table issue ... find duplicate high value in row and return column title
I have the following table:

_____apple      pear    plum    grape   cherry

alice     __5   ____0   ___5    ___3    ____1

bob ___2    ____1   ___0    ___1    ____2

cindy   ___1    ____2   __3 ___6    _____4

And I need to find duplicate high value in row and return column title. Otherwise return the max value.

For example for row "alice" the 2 highest values are "5" so the 2 columns returned would be "apple" and "plum"

for "bob" it would be "apple" and "cherry"

For Cindy since there's only  "grape"

I tried the following formula:   =index($B$1:$F$1, match (large(B2:F2,1),B2:F2,0))

and it returns the first largest value, but I cant get the 2nd largest value with:   =index($B$1:$F$1, match (large(B2:F2,2),B2:F2,0))

because it again returns "apple" as "apple" is seen as both the first and 2nd largest value.

I tried the following formula to get the 2nd largest value in the first row:

=index($B$1:$F$1, match (large(B2:F2,2),B2:F2,-1)) and it works to return "plum" for the first row, but for the second row instead of returning "cherry" it returns "apple".

=index($B$1:$F$1, match (large(B3:F3,1),B3:F3,-1)) atually return "cherry"

but then i have different formulas in different rows and im confused. I need a consistent formula to get the two values.

Please any help would be appreciated. see,s like it should be a simple problem. But I have been racking my brain.

Answer (score 0):

@Vadim, try this:

```
=FILTER($B$1:$F$1, B2:F2=INDEX($B2:$F2, MATCH (LARGE(B2:F2,1), B2:F2, 0)))
```

**HOW IT WORKS**

In short, FILTER filters in *all* entries in B1:F1 where the corresponding value in row 2 *matches* the largest number in row 2 (regardless of how many matches there are).